# Why is my docker registry refusing connections from VMs in my local network but not the host?

Tags: docker, ssl, containers, libvirt, podman

For context - I am attempting to deploy OKD in an air-gapped environment, which requires mirroring an image registry. This private, secured registry is then pulled from by other machines in the network during the installation process.

To describe the environment - the host machine where the registry container is running is running Centos 7.6. The other machines are all VMs running Fedora coreOS in using libvirt. The VMs and the host are connected using a virtual network created using libvirt which includes DHCP settings (dnsmasq) for the VMs to give them static IPs. The host machine also hosts the DNS server, which, as far as I can tell is configured properly, as I can ping every machine from every other machine using its fully qualified domain name and access specific ports (such as the port the apache server listens on). Podman is used instead of Docker for container management for OKD, but as far as I can tell the commands are exactly the same.

I have the registry running in the air-gapped environment using the following command:

```
sudo podman run --name mirror-registry -p 5000:5000 -v /opt/registry/data:/var/lib/registry:z \
-v /opt/registry/auth:/auth:z -v /opt/registry/certs:/certs:z -e REGISTRY_AUTH=htpasswd \
-e "REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM=Registry Realm" -e REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH=/auth/htpasswd \
-e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/registry.pem -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/registry-key.pem \
-d docker.io/library/registry:latest
```

It is accessible using `curl -u username:password https://host-machine.example.local:5000/v2/_catalog` which returns `{"repositories":[]}`. I believe this confirms that my TLS and authorization configurations are correct. However, if I transfer the ca.pem file (used to sign the SSL certificates the registry uses) over to one of the VM's on the virtual network, and attempt to use the same `curl` command, I get an error:

```
connect to 192.168.x.x port 5000 failed: Connection refused
Failed to connect to host-machine.example.local port 5000: Connection refused
Closing connection 0
```

This is quite strange to me, as I've been able to use this method to communicate with the registry from the VMs in the past, and I'm not sure what has changed.

After some further digging, it seems like there is some sort of issue with the port itself, but I can't be sure where the issue is stemming from. For example, If I run `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN` on the host, I receive a line indicating that podman (conmon) is listening on the correct port:

`tcp          0          0 0.0.0.0:5000        0.0.0.0:*        LISTEN      48337/conmon`

but if I test whether the port is accessible from the VM, (`nc -zvw5 192.168.x.x 5000`) I get a similar error: `Ncat: Connection refused.` If I use the same test on any of the other listening ports on the host, it indicates successful connections to those ports.

Please note, I have completely disabled firewalld, so as far as I know, all ports are open.

I'm not sure if the issue is with my DNS settings, or the virtual network, or with the registry itself and I'm not quite sure how to further diagnose the issue. Any insight would be much appreciated.